# IOS: leave space from a nsstring and manage commas

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

I have this nsstring

```
Manhattan, New York, Stati Uniti
```

I want leave all space and I can use replacestring with @"", it's ok for me;
my very problem is that I want put all element separate by commas in an array, is it possible?

for example the array'll be array = [Manhattan] [New York] [Stati Uniti]

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSString`'s [`componentsSeparatedByString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a):

```
NSString *list = @"Manhattan, New York, Stati Uniti";
NSArray *cities = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

`cities` now holds: `{ @"Manhattan", @"New York", @"Stati Uniti" }`

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
NSArray *newArray = [stateString componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```